# How do you compare samples if they are not Independent and Identical Distributed (IID)?

Tags: statistics, dataset, comparison, independent-set

I have 2 questions.

Nr. 1: I have a simulation model running for 1 year (after the warm-up period) that simulates the patients coming into a clinic for their treatment (set up daily) (a patient may come in for their treatment once every week for the next 5 weeks on Mondays). One may consider this as a daily simulation termination.

The first question that I have regarding *Independent and Identical Distributions* (IID) is that I need to compare the number of patients that are present in the clinic (let us say, on Mondays). Yet, the number of patients each Monday may be different from Monday to Monday (this Monday, we have 100 patients; next Monday we have 105 patients; next Monday we have 97 patients). Each day is independent from the other, however, I do not believe that each day (in this case, Mondays) is identically distributed (taking in consideration that *n* is different). Thus, the question is: how can I compare, statistically independent days that are not identically distributed?

Nr. 2: A patient is scheduled for their first visit for 60 minutes (60 minutes window). Even through the doctors, nurses, pharmacists (and all the staff) have their own distributions regarding the time provided to the patient (thus, IID), the other problem that I face is that each patient has different needs: (for example)

Patient A: doctor **and** nurse.

Patient B: doctor **and** nurse **and** pharmacist.

Patient C: doctor **and** nurse **and** social worker.

Therefore, even if the patient is given 60 minutes for its appointment, because there are different staff interacting with the patient, are the durations of the patient’s visit IID in this context? They are independent (no link between patients); they should be identically distributed as they (patient and staff) have only 60 minutes at their disposal, yet, I am not certain about this.

In the case where data-sets are not IID, how can they be compared?

Any help and guidance is very much appreciated.

Comment: Interesting topic, but since this is a discussion question, it's suitable for stats.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Thank you. I will post there.